# Where can I check the running cost of a Databricks SQL Endpoint?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, cost-management

Where can I check the running cost of a Databricks SQL Endpoint?

I checked the Cost Analysis and there is an item called SQL database, is that it?